# Ubuntu 16.04 CUDA 9.0 Installation Problem : The driver installation is unable to locate the kernel source.

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda

I am trying to install CUDA 9.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Tesla P100.

I am now using local runfile, but it always emmits error:

```
Installing the NVIDIA display driver...
The driver installation is unable to locate the kernel source. Please make 
sure that the kernel source packages are installed and set up correctly.
If you know that the kernel source packages are installed and set up 
correctly, you may pass the location of the kernel source with the '-- 
kernel-source-path' flag.
```

And uname result is

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-36-generic
```

My /usr/src is like this:

```
$ ll /usr/src/
total 141M
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 127M  1月 22  2016 linux_4.4.0.orig.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 9.5K  9月 26 18:53 linux_4.4.0-137.163.dsc
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  15M  9月 26 18:53 linux_4.4.0-137.163.diff.gz
drwxr-xr-x 29 root root 4.0K 10月  3 21:37 linux-4.4.0/
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4.0K 10月 24 06:27 linux-headers-4.4.0-138/
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4.0K 10月 24 06:27 linux-headers-4.4.0-138-generic/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K 10月 24 19:45 linux-meta-4.4.0.139.145/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   45 10月 25 00:05 linux-source-4.4.0.tar.bz2 -> 
linux-source-4.4.0/linux-source-4.4.0.tar.bz2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   47 10月 25 05:01 linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2 -> 
linux-source-4.15.0/linux-source-4.15.0.tar.bz2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  18K 10月 25 14:18 linux-meta_4.4.0.139.145.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  22K 10月 25 14:18 linux-meta_4.4.0.139.145.dsc
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4.0K 11月  9 16:00 linux-headers-4.15.0-36/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K 11月  9 21:19 cudnn_samples_v7/
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4.0K 11月  9 23:22 nvidia-410.48/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K 11月 12 16:49 cudnn_samples_v5/
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4.0K 11月 13 11:50 linux-headers-4.15.0-36-generic/
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4.0K 11月 15 06:01 linux-headers-4.4.0-139/
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4.0K 11月 15 06:01 linux-headers-4.4.0-139-generic/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K 11月 15 06:01 linux-source-4.4.0/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K 11月 15 06:02 linux-source-4.15.0/
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4.0K 11月 21 11:55 linux-headers-4.15.0-39/
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4.0K 11月 21 11:55 linux-headers-4.15.0-39-generic/
```

My installtion setting is

1. no OpenGL
2. no sample
3. yes nvidia-x-config.

Please help me.